# Placing code outside of document root problems with Apache and Django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am having trouble fulfilling the Django recommendation for code placement.  I have searched google and beyond trying all types of VirtualHost configurations.  However I cannot get the Django site to work with Apache like it does with Django's built in test web server.

I am using Django 1.5.4 and mod_wsgi

The Django documentation states that:

> Where should this code live?
>
> If your background is in plain old PHP (with no use of modern frameworks), you’re probably used to putting code under the Web server’s document root (in a place such as /var/www). With Django, you don’t do that. It’s not a good idea to put any of this Python code within your Web server’s document root, because it risks the possibility that people may be able to view your code over the Web. That’s not good for security.
>
> Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as /home/mycode.

And in trying to do that I am failing.

Here is an example of my directory structure: I have /home/user/djangoRoot which I want for the document root and /home/user/djangoCode for where I want to put the code.  I have followed the tutorial running `django-admin.py startproject djangoSite` and all the folders and files are created as they should.  Database sync works great. I can view the site when I use Django's built in testing web server.  But I feel like something is wrong with my apache virtual host because I cannot view the site the same way with apache.

Again, in the spirit of keeping code out of the document root, I want djangoRoot as my root directory and djangoCode for my code directory (with djangoSite/djangoSite directories in it that were created after running the `django-admin.py start project djangoSite` command).

I have tried

1. Making the DjangoCode/DjangoSite my root directory, but I can see the file structure inthe browser
2. Eliminating the DocumentRoot from the VirtualHost as quite a few suggessted.
3. And I have tried what I gathered from django and the rest

None worked.

So here is my current apache virtualhost

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/user/djangoCode/djangoSite/djangoSite

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

DocumentRoot /home/user/djangoRoot
<Directory /home/user/djangoRoot>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /djangoRoot /home/user/djangoCode/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py

<Directory "/home/user/djangoCode/djangoSite/djangoSite/wsgi.py">
<Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
    
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

This currently only allows me to see document root with no sign of django.
Is my virtual host configured wrong?
Am I taking this "code outside of document root too far"?

Comment: That setup will serve your site under /djangoRoot - is that the URL you're looking at?

Comment: Well that is the folder I am using as my doc root for this example.  I have done this kind of thing for typical html/php sites and have had no problem with it. Again maybe my problem is in my understanding of the "code in document root" issue and I'm taking that too far.  None the less I am obviously missing something to get Django to work with Apache (and have followed tutorials and googled suggestions).

Comment: But this hasn't got anything to do with the folder where your code is. The first parameter to WSGIScriptAlias is the base URL for your site. So you have to go to that URL to see it. But it's quite separate to where the code actually is.

Comment: AGREED! So what the heck is meant by the advice not to put your code at the document root? Isn't putting it in a sub directory of the root just as much a problem? Why do some people say to leave out the DocumentRoot from the virtualhost and get it to work? Everywhere I check this advice is echoed but never is a full example given to show how this works! Basically how do I fulfill the security issue and get apache to serve my Django site? No example I have tried works yet (other than through Django's built in test web server).

Comment: Maybe this is my confusion: The code placement warning uses the example of /var/www as the document root. Then it says to place code in /home/mycode. I am reading this as all beginning at the main root of the OS. Are they really meaning that the document root is /var/www and the code is /var/www/home/mycode? Again just a sub directory, but does this satisfy the security warning?

Comment: No, your original reading is correct. Moving this to an answer, as it's getting too long for comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really don't understand why you're finding this so hard, but you're clearly not following me at all. The point of the explanation in the docs is that the place where you code lives in your filesystem is *completely independent* from the point that Apache serves it at. The latter is given by the first parameter to WSGIScriptAlias. The former is given by the second parameter.

The document root is the default place for Apache to serve files from. But you're not serving files, you're running code to serve dynamic content. So, you proxy to the WSGI app, at the point given by the first parameter to WSGIScriptAlias. **That is the root URL of your site.** In the example you've given, that means that - assuming your domain name is `example.com` - your Django app will be accessible under `example.com/djangoRoot`. If you actually visited that URL in your browser, you'd see whatever page is configured under `/` in your urls.py. That is almost certainly not what you want. In the vast majority of cases, the first parameter - as shown in the docs - should just be `/`.

So I'm not sure why you think that goes against the security warning. Here, the document root stays at whatever it is by default - usually `/var/www` - but the code lives in `/home/user/djangoCode/...` and is served at `/`.

Comment: And it works. I did understand the theory as you explained so I don't think there was any issue us understanding each other.  My problem was when I went to my site all I saw was the index of / showing all files (of which there were none).  However when I added /djangoRoot to the url it worked.  So I changed my WSGIScriptAlias' first parameter to / and it worked just with the regular url. See I had tried that once, but got errors accessing root. Can't say why it works now.

However I greatly appreciate the conversation. It did help me understand deeper.

Comment: @Daniel how to access in django settings the physcial location in filesystem of the served django app? the `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))` which in my other server uwsgi+nginx configuration returns the physcial path in my apache + mod_wsgi configuratio return the `/var/www` ?

Comment: @Daniel @andi OK. Fixed. It was just about replacing `__name__` with `__file__`